# Здравствуйте! Правильно ли писать: " Возьмите бутылок"?

Tags: окончания

Возьмите бутылок
Правильно ли употреблять в этом случае окончание "ок"? Или нужно написать бутылки?

Answer (score 2):

**КОММУНИКАТИВНОСТЬ**

**На столе стоят бутылки.**

Возьмите бутылки, а то мешают. Это правильный В.п.

Возьмите бутылок, а то мешают. Это неправильный Р.п.

В конкретной **речевой ситуации** используется **нужный падеж**, оба не подойдут.

**Пояснение**

Правильно:  возьмите (что?) **бутылки** (В.п., окончание множ.числ И).

Неправильно:  возьмите (чего?)  **бутылок** (Р.п., нулевое окончание мн.числа).

**Сравнить:**

возьмите еще бутылок,  а то не хватит (родительный партитивный, обозначает часть чего-либо)

нет (чего?) бутылок (Р.п. при отрицании)

возьмите десять **бутылок** воды (Р.п. в счетном обороте)

возьмите **бутылок** десять воды (Р.п. в счетном обороте, приблизительное количество, обратный  порядок слов).

**БРАТЬ**, беру, берёшь; брал, -ла, брало; нсв. (св. ***взять**)*. 1. **кого-что**, **чем, во что.** Захватывать, схватывать рукой, руками или каким-л. инструментом, орудием, находящимся в руках; принимать в руки. Б. ложку, газету. Б. хлеб с тарелки. Б. бельё из шкафа. Б. тряпку двумя руками, пальцами. Б. вату пинцетом. Б. за плечи, за талию кого-л. Б. аккорды (муз.). Б. высокий (низкий) мяч (спорт.). Б. ребёнка на руки (поднимать, усаживать на руках или коленях).

Answer (score 1):

Возьмите бутылки.

Возьмите бутылок.

Оба варианты допустимы.

......................................................................................................................................................................

*Возьмите бутылки* - тут дополнение более конкретно по значению, винительныйй падеж вообще более конкретен, чем родительный. Традиционно этот винительный считается винительных "полного охвата предмета".

*Возьмите бутылок*  - родительный при переходном глаголе в принципе отличается лишь меньшей конкретностью, меньшей определённостью, тут не ощущается полный охват предмета, какие-то его пределы. Есть термин "родительный частичного охвата".

......................................................................................................................................................................

Взять:

1. ***ч т о*** (полный охват предмета действием). • Взять билеты в театр. Взять молоко у молочницы.
2. ***ч е г о*** (частичный охват предмета действием). • Взять *хлеба и молока* на завтрак. Где взять *сил и решимост*и для противодействия? (Добролюбов).

Родительный часто используется вместо винительного именно ***при вещественных и отвлечённых существительных***. Хотя бутылка, конечно, не вещество (хлеб, молоко) и не отвлечённое существительное (силы, решимость).

......................................................................................................................................................................

Глагол ***взять*** может быть синонимичен глаголу ***набрать*** - глаголу с накопительным префиксом на-. Такие глаголы замечательно управляют родительным падежом: набрать бутылок, набрать разных банок, набрать конфет, набрать компьютеров и т. д.

Так что *конкретно-предметные существительные* при глаголе взять ***могут*** использоваться в родительном падеже, однако явно только во множественном числе.

Взять камень, взять камни, взять камней, но не взять камня.

Взять компьютер, взять компьютеры, взять компьютеров, но не взять компьютера.

......................................................................................................................................................................

Вот найденные в Гугл Букс примеры сочетаемости глагола ***взять*** с родительным падежом конкретного существительного :

Влад Костромин. Грибные дни.  2022.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дмитрий Исаков. Акулу съели!: фантастические произведения. 1992

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

......................................................................................................................................................................

***Короче говоря:***

*Возьмите бутылки* - это история про "конкретные бутылки в известном количестве".

*Возьмите бутылок* - это история "про бутылки в целом, про бутылки в каком-то количестве".